# onRequestPermissionsResult without extends

Tags: javascript, android

I doing a library for adobe Air and it´s have a activity in course and I can acess this activity trough method getActivity() but how I can listen onRequestPermissionsResult()

Example:

```
Activity activity = myContext.getActivity()
activity.requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);

//How i can listen onRequestPermissionsResult() inside that´s activity?
```

Comment: which class you are trying to extend?

Comment: Only `Activity` and `Fragment` can receive permission results. If you need the results in some other class you'll have to come up with a way to let the activity/fragment pass the result to that object. Since you've hardly shown us any code it's difficult to say what a good solution would look like in your case.

Comment: The code is basicly this, i have a context thats i get a activity and i request permission, starting at this simple point, have a way to listen onRequestPermissionsResult()?

Answer (score 1):

You need to override this method,

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
```

And this method is of `Activity` class. That you already have.

If you dont know, how to request permission [read this](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Comment: i doing a library for adobe Air and it´s have a activity in course and i can acess this activity trough method getActivity() but how i can listen onRequestPermissionsResult()

Comment: my suggested method you need to use in Activity, of which myContext object is.

Answer (score 0):

You can write onRequestPermissionResult inside Activity class . don't worry if you ask to permission in fragment then also result will be received in activity.

May be useful to you.

Comment: i dont have a mainActivity

Answer (score 0):

Try this library
https://github.com/alhazmy13/Gota

It internally starts a new activity to check permissions you need and fires event on completion.

```
new Gota.Builder(this)
            .withPermissions(Manifest.permission.CAMERA,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)
            .requestId(1)
            .setListener(this)
            .check();
```

and listener

```
   @Override
public void onRequestBack(int requestId, @NonNull GotaResponse gotaResponse) {
    if(gotaResponse.isGranted(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
       // Your Code
    }
}
```